# Can someone tell me how to prove $\cap_{i\in I}(B \setminus A_i) = B \setminus (\cup_{i\in I} A_i)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

Can someone tell me how to prove  $\cap_{i\in I}(B \setminus A_i) = B \setminus (\cup_{i\in I} A_i)$

Comment: Let the definitions do the work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By set inclusion:

Consider $x \in \cap_{i\in I}(B \setminus A_i)$.  Then $x \in B \setminus A_i$ for all $i \in I \implies x \notin A_i$ for all $i \in I \implies x \notin \cup_{i\in I} A_i \implies x \in B \setminus (\cup_{i\in I} A_i)$

Now consider $x \in B \setminus (\cup_{i\in I} A_i)$.  Then $x \notin \cup_{i\in I} A_i \implies x \notin A_i$ for all $i \in I \implies x \in B \setminus A_i$ for all $i \in I \implies x \in \cap_{i\in I}(B \setminus A_i)$

Comment: This is great!  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

$\cap_{i\in I}(B \setminus A_i) = \cap_{i\in I}(B \cap A_i^c) = B \cap (\cap_{i \in I} A_i^c) = B \cap (\cup_{i \in I} A_i)^c = B \setminus (\cup_{i\in I} A_i)$.

Comment: Thanks for the help Vaneet but I got kind of lost.  I don't know what the little C means you added.  Can you help me understand what that represents?

Comment: That little $c$ is the complement $A\setminus B = A \cap B^c$. Then, there is that intersection can go inside and the next step is intersection of complements is complement of union (De Morgan's Law). Does this help?

Comment: Yes. thank you!

Comment: So after looking at this closer I would propose that ∩i∈I(B∖Ai) ≠ ∩i∈I(B∩Aci). Let say B = {1,4,5} and F = {{1,2,3},{2,3,5},{5,6,7}} thus A1 = {1,2,3}, A2 = {2,3,5}, and A3 = {5,6,7} then we compute  ∩i∈I(B∖Ai) as follows:

∩i∈I(B∖Ai) = 
∩i∈I(B\A1, B\A2, B\A3) =
∩i∈I(({1,4,5}\{1,2,3})({1,4,5}\{2,3,5})({1,4,5}\{5,6,7})) =
∩i∈I({4,5},{1,4},{1,4}) = {4}

Now we compute ∩i∈I(B∩Aci) as follows:
∩i∈I(B∩Aci) =
∩i∈I(B∩Ac1, B∩Ac2, B∩Ac3) = ∩i∈I(({1,4,5}∩{5,6,7},{1,4,5}∩{1,6,7},},{1,4,5}∩{1,2,3}) =
∩i∈I({5},{1},{1}) = Null

{4} ≠ Null  therfore ∩i∈I(B∖Ai) ≠ ∩i∈I(B∩Aci).

Comment: I tried really hard to make the formatting easier to read but the site keeps deleting it.  Sorry the above is not easy on the eyes.